# WordPress As A Symfony (Symfony3) Subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

I am running a Symfony app on DigitalOcean. I have setup the entire site and created VirtualHosts. I need to run WordPress as a subdirectory (/blog). From what I know Symfony tends to ignore subdirectories in /web so I created /web/blog and installed WordPress in it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.com/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/site.com/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

On localhost installations **without VirtualHost** this runs perfectly.

But on the live server, lets say at 21.21.21.21 I have Symfony running and 21.21.21.21/blog should open blog but it doesn't, instead goes to a Symfony 404. Whereas 21.21.21.21/blog/index.php runs the blog (WordPress).

The WordPress .htaccess which lives in /web/blog is as follows:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have tried tinkering with this with some answers on the web, nothing changes.

Comment: Are you sure that the blog directory have the right file owning configuration?

Comment: @El_Matella I'm not sure what that means. please help me understand, I'll do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your vhost so that you exclude your `/blog` directory from symphony rules. And you will also need to change to `AllowOverride All` since you are using `.htaccess` in `/blog`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.com/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/site.com/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog(/.+)? [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Be sure to restart apache after changes.

**WordPress .htaccess Changes:**

```
 Options -Indexes
 DirectoryIndex index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. it worked to some extent. Now 21.21.21.21/blog shows the default apache2 directory listing. It's listing all the WordPress files but not picking up index.php automatically?

Comment: Also I learnt something new, now I know what AllowOverride does. Thanks for that.

Comment: To fix listing files.... Add `Options -Indexes` at the top of your .htaccess file and then below that add `DirectoryIndex index.php`

Comment: Did I do it right? I've updated the .htaccess in the question. WordPress has now started to show but it's all WordPress 404s. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Fixed it! I had changed the siteurl earlier to 21.21.21.21/blog/index.php in the DB. As soon as I changed it, it worked like a charm. You are a lifesaver.