# Need To Run Symfony + ReactJS & WordPress Together

Tags: wordpress, symfony, reactjs, virtualhost, lamp

For our project we decided for a Symfony app and a WordPress blog. It basically runs an entire installation of WordPress as a subdirectory called `/blog` inside the `/web` folder of Symfony.

We setup a quick coming soon page on www.example.com/ (Symfony Route: /) and kept running WordPress blog on www.example.com/blog/

Details about that setup on my question about WordPress as a Symfony subdirectory:
[WordPress As A Symfony (Symfony3) Subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895342/wordpress-as-a-symfony-symfony3-subdirectory)

Over the course of development we let Symfony power the REST API and developed the application frontend with ReactJS. I am very unsure about the deployment. How will this work?

Note: I can't display WordPress as a React frontend and WordPress REST API because over 200 posts are now designed using a page builder provided by the theme (Lesson learned).

What options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a minified version of the React app and load it from a twig template. If you are using any react router, you will have to deal with the base url of your panel to make the urls be valid.

For instance, if you develop with a local server:
localhost:3000/my/fancy/panel

in production can happen that this url becomes

www.yourdomain.com/users/panel/my/fancy/panel

You you have to configure your router and routes to prefix /users/panel in production environment.

In my case I inject that base url in the tpl or twig and the app doesn't need to care about the environment.

Your app needs to display the Wordpress posts?

Comment: I use react router and split code with redux, how do I create this in a minified js? Also it deals with about 10-15 different routes, will they work if I open an in app route directly? It's a fairly large react app

Comment: I use this as a project template to get the dev environment and production tasks working. https://github.com/jpsierens/webpack-react-redux Regarding to your routing question, if the full path is the same it will work, if not you will get an empty screen or a 404 error depending of how you have configured your routes in Symfony. In my case I have setup a wildcard url to redirect all the traffic to /users/panel/whatever to the react app. In terms of Symfony this means loading the panel twig with the React app and let the react router deal with it.

Comment: So I made it work using the method of minified build on a Symfony route, I appreciate the help. But I am stuck with the 404 problem. Let's say I am have category route www.example.com/category/denim, It works perfectly when I navigate to it from the home page, but if I refresh the same page I get a Symfony 404. I am unable to understand from your last comment on what I should do?

Comment: That is because Symfony undestand that it has to manage the route and there is no controller configured for that. You need a wildcard route in your routes.yml, something like 
         wildcard_route:
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Controllername:controllerFunctionName }
    path:   /category/{whatever}
    requirements:
        whatever: .*
    defaults:
        whatever: null 
        The controller function just loads the twig template with your react app. Then te react router will care about the path.